# Why is "interface" not a valid name in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I add a folder called "interface" in my Scala project in IntelliJ IDEA,
there is a error: "Not a valid package name".

Why is this and is this possible to change?

Comment: Do you know what an interface is in programming? It's probably a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use reserved keywords.

see the list of reserved keywords:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9